# Can a Unity GameObject Array be used to emulate ToggleGroup like behavior

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, gameobject

This app has panels with collections of buttons which are on "Play" disabled. The goal is to utilize a GameOject array to manage these buttons so that only one button can ever be enabled at a time. In an ToggleGroup, it is possible to force only one Toggle object to be selected at any time.

Though growing in Unity c# skills, i readily admit to being more beginner than intermediate in skills. So, any guidance is most appreciated.

The first step was to test the use of ToggleGroups, but Toggles cannot accept the c# script associated with the buttons, which, when enabled, loads a Prefab from an AssetBundle.

Once ToggleGroups were taken off the table, i have been researching the use of an array of GameObjects. Several sources show how in the simplistic manner, to create an array of buttons, and upon Start(), make the buttons inactive. But i am unclear how to emulate the ToggleGroup functionality in an array.

Here is the base of my "buttonMgtArray" script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class buttonMgtArray : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] button;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        button[0].SetActive(false);
        button[1].SetActive(false);
        button[2].SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

There are no errors at this time because i am attempting to identify how to emulate the desired behavior in the context of GameObject Array.

To better illustrate the behavior i am attempting to invoke, this screencap may help explain the goal.

[Button Behavior Explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tL0oG.png)

I am very pleased to report that @Stanley had a very elegant solution that provides the toggling emulation. The key was to apply the script to the button that enabled the hidden button, which are the array references. Here is the final code. Thanks much to @Stanley

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class buttonMgtArray : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] buttonArray;

    public void DisableAllButtonsExcept(int i)
    {
        foreach (GameObject buttonGameObject in buttonArray)
        {
            buttonGameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        buttonArray[i].SetActive(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF i understand you correctly you want to use your buttons like radio buttons.
I see that no one has answered your question yet so i'll give it a quick go.

There are more ways of doing this and better ways, but this one does work.

```
public void DisableAllButtonsExcept(int i) {
    foreach(GameObject buttonGameObject in buttonArray) {
        buttonGameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
    buttonArray[i].SetActive(true);
}
```

---

**before**
[image: Before running code]

---

**after**
[image: After running code]

> *Button number 2 is kept because arrays start at 0*

[image]

change the parameters in the onClick event to match its position in the array

Comment: Hello @Stanley. Thanks for the very quick reply. Yes, the action is much like a radio button, but in this case, all other buttons are not active other than the selected one. I am going to try out your recommendations here later this evening and will gladly reply back and update my progress.

Comment: @muckletone great! Looking forward to hearing from you

Comment: Hi again @Stanley. Here are my findings. I made one small adjustment, i set the "DisableAllButtonsExcept" to "3" so that all the buttons are not enabled upon start. Using your example, what doesnt happen is the toggling. In other words, If "element 0" is enabled, and then i enable "element 1", "element 0" isn't disabled. I suspect i very poorly explained what i meant by "toggling" the buttons. I will do some playing around on this for a little longer this evening, i think you have given me something to start with, for which i am very appreciative.

Comment: @muckletone do you want all but one button to be active or only one button at a time active? And setting the value to a number instead of changing it dynamically based upon the button that is clicked will not work

Comment: Hello @Stanley. The goal is that only one button at a time can ever be active, with them all starting in the deactivated state. I know that this question has been rated as not having done enough research, but i admit, i am not even sure what the correct coding syntax/terminology would be to produce better research. That is why i referenced the Unity Toggle/ToggleGroup, as it represents the behavior. By using index number of 3, i was thinking it would insure all buttons were off. Apparently that is not a good approach. Will be working more tonight on it. Thanks ever so much.

Comment: @muckletone like this? https://i.gyazo.com/0b41210d97c9af651ff1cff90ff4cd7f.mp4

Comment: Hello @Stanley, you are too kind. Yes, that is the kind of behavior. Give me a few minutes, and i will provide some screenshots of my tests. There is a nuance i should try to explain, which i think better done with some screenshots. Thank you very much.

Comment: @muckletone updated the answer and it should work properly now :)

Comment: Hello and thanks @Stanley. I will put this through the paces very shortly and let you know. I will add to the original question the screencap with notes to better describe the solution i am attempting to solve. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Stanley, wanted to report this works EXACTLY like i was looking for. I am now just study this code (which is simple to you, but probably something i need to study better). Thanks a million for this solution. I felt certain that using an Array was the basis for emulating the toggle mechanism. But you have provided a very elegant solution.

Comment: @muckletone perfect im glad i could help, if you could mark the question as answered that would be perfect and if you ever need me again, just send me a DM and i will be glad to help!

Comment: indeed i would reach out. I just marked the question as answered. And soon as my level allows, i most certainly would DM you. Again, many thanks.

Comment: @muckletone thank you, very glad i could help out! while you dont have the level for it: here is my discord LIFE#2123